# MySQL update query failed

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update 2 columns through two different textboxes, but after submitting it, it shows 0 values in the database.

HTML code:

```
<form action="update_quantity.php" method="post" class="c-shop-form-1">
     <tbody>   
          <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            { 
               $id2=$row['id'];

               echo " <tr> 

                <td>{$row['name']}

               <td></td>

                 <td>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control c-square c-theme' style='width: 90px;' placeholder='Quantity' name='Quantity' id='Quantity'>
                 </td> 

                </td> 
                <td>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control c-square c-theme' style='width: 90px;' placeholder='Quantity' name='Quantity2' id='Quantity2'>
                </td> 

               </tr>";
            }?> 
        </tbody>        
    </table>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-square center c-btn-bold c-btn-uppercase">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP code: upddate_quantity.php

```
$quant = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Quantity']);
$id1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Quantity2']);

$sql = "UPDATE vm_elements SET physicalStock='$quant', transitQuantity='$id1'  WHERE id='1'";
//$res = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error()." in ".$sql);
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql))
{
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} 
else
{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

I need help. I don't understand what is missing.

Comment: `$quant = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Quantity']);
$id1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Quantity2']);` these are not strings right? you can directly send post variables to the query, without `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @Raghav: I tried without mysqli_real_escape but it wasn't working. Anything else that you figured out and i missed?

Comment: Try to echo SQL Query you will get query with values and run the query in DB (phpMyadmin). just check everything fine in SQL perspective.

Comment: @Raghav: Sql query is returning this :"UPDATE vm_elements SET physicalStock='', transitQuantity='' WHERE id=''Records added successfully."

Comment: I don't understand my mistake. Can you tell me what have done wrong?

Comment: @Raghav Are you really trying to get him vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: @RCV That HTML is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you - at least it should provide more information with error handling. First off add a name to your button:

```
<button type="submit" name="RCV" id="RCV" value="submit" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-square center c-btn-bold c-btn-uppercase">Submit</button>
```

Then you can try this:

```
/* Check your mysqli connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['RCV'])) {

    try {

        $physStock = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Quantity']);
        $transQuant = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Quantity2']);    
        $id = 1;        

        $sql = "UPDATE vm_elements SET physicalStock=?, transitQuantity=?  WHERE id=?";

        if(!($stmt = $link->prepare($sql))) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $physStock, $transQuant, $id)) {
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }       

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        } else {
            echo "Records added successfully.";
        }

        $stmt->close();

    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e){
        //Handle exception $e
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work for you have a look at all of the POST variables sent from the form by using:

```
 print_r($_POST)
```

Actually looking at it again - it might be more to do with your HTML than your PHP script. You have the form beginning inside the table - just outside of the tbody tag and ending outside of it. You should rearrange your html tags - place the entire form within the table and try it out.

```
    <tbody>   
        <form action="update_quantity.php" method="post" class="c-shop-form-1">
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 

                   $id2=$row['id'];

                   echo "<tr><td>{$row['name']}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control c-square c-theme' style='width: 90px;' placeholder='Quantity' name='Quantity' id='Quantity'>
                        </td>  

                        <td>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control c-square c-theme' style='width: 90px;' placeholder='Quantity' name='Quantity2' id='Quantity2'>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>";
            }?> 
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><button type="submit" name="RCV" id="RCV" value="submit" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-square center c-btn-bold c-btn-uppercase">Submit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </form>     
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Can You tell me why did you use this? "physicalStock=?, transitQuantity=?  WHERE id=?"

Comment: Forget about the changes in the PHP script for now. Have you tried print_r($_POST) and changing the HTML table structure??

Comment: yes. this is what i am getting after  print_r($_POST) ="Array ( [Quantity] => [Quantity2] => [RCV] => submit )"

Comment: Have you changed the table structure to have the form all contained within the tbody?

Comment: Is the print_r($_POST) output the same with the table changes?

Comment: yeah. same output after changing html

Comment: Stupid question - you are putting in some random text when you submit the form to test it, right? HTML placeholder values (e.g. "Quantity" in your case) aren't posted